# Argument error for my pages

Tags: php

I am having the this problem in my first page and i do not know how to fix it,please help me

`Warning: Missing argument 1 for isblockedip(), called in /home/u425835176/public_html/shad0w.php on line 174 and defined in /home/u425835176/public_html/core.php on line 4715`

**Function**

```
function isblockedip($var)
{
    $text = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $rez = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lib3rtymrc_blockedip");
    $i=0;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rez))
    {
        $var[$i]=$row[1];
        $i++;
    }  

    $result = count($var);

    for ($i=0;$i<$result;$i++)
    {
        $ausg = stristr($text, $var[$i]);
        if(strlen($ausg)>0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

in shad0w.php

```
if(isblockedip())
    {
////here comes the message
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

Either pass a variable when you call the function:

```
if(isblockedip($somevar))
```

Or give `$var` a default value in the function declaration:

```
function isblockedip($var = array())
```

In the function block, `$var` is an array, so it looks like in *shad0w.php* there may be an array of some sort that function `isblockedip` may need.

If you *never* pass a pre-existing array to `isblockedip` then change the function delcaration to:

```
function isblockedip()
{
$var = array();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isblockedip())
```

is missing the parameter $var
Call it like `if(isblockedip($var))`

Answer (score 0):

If your "Problem" is the Warning, Solution goes here:

the function `isblockedip($var)`
expects the parameter `$var`, but you do not call this function with a variable:
    `isblockedip()`
what leads to the `Warning: Missing argument 1 for isblockedip()...[..]`